# What are the things to be included in the CMakeLists.txt file for using gazebo plugins with ROS?

Tags: ros, cmake, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want a plugin for using camera in gazebo with ros integration. I already have the .cpp file for the plugin but dont know what all is to be included in the CMakeLists.txt file.
Please Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13654/what-are-the-things-to-be-included-in-the-cmakelists.txt-file-for-using-gazebo-plugins-with-ros?/) by [vatsal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2660/vatsal/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

if you are "just" looking for the CMakeList.txt see below. It also depends on your plugin what 'includes/packages' are required. In addition you need your program to be in a catkin / ros package. (see the tutorial link below)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gazebo_tutorials)

# Load catkin and all dependencies required for this package
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  roscpp 
  gazebo_ros 
)

# Depend on system install of Gazebo
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/simple_world_plugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES})

catkin_package(
  DEPENDS 
    roscpp 
    gazebo_ros 
)
```

As mentioned previously you should go through the tutorial. This is from where I got the above code: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_plugins

To understand the CMakeList file, read here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [m4k](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2610/m4k/) with karma: 61 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0